# I can't exit from search or application mode

Tags: gnome, 20.04, ubuntu-gnome

On Ubuntu 20.04, when I active search in application mode (<kbd>super</kbd> or <kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>F1</kbd>), I can't exit.

All applications are blocked; I can only close them.

I am obliged to close the session (dash to panel is operational), or <kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>F2</kbd> and `r` to reinitialize gnome.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

I solved the problem with the version 39 of Dash to panel.
In order to install the last version, I had to edit metadata.json and replace version 9999 (?) with version 37.
And update with firefox and the extension for gnome.